# php using for to loop words without any space between them

Tags: php

How can I achieve making words loops without any space between them using *for*

Here is my code:

```
function a($var) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < ; $i++)
    {
        echo "a";
    }
}

a(3);
```

I want it to make loops like:

```
a(3);

output: aaa
```

but I get an error saying

```
syntax error, unexpected ';'
```

Comment: **`$i < $var`**

Answer (score 3):

**Syntax Error**

I think you are missing a limiting factor if for loop

```
for ($i = 0; $i < ; $i++)
```

should be

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $some_limiting_factor_here; $i++)
```

in your case $some_limiting_factor_here could be $var